# About the triple product $\vec{A}\circ(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})$ or $\vec{\nabla}\circ(\vec{U}\times\vec{V})$

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

We know that

\begin{equation}
\vec{A}\circ(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})=\vec{B}\circ(\vec{C}\times\vec{A})=\vec{C}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{B}) \qquad (1).
\end{equation}

In some reference I found that

\begin{equation}
\vec{A}\circ(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})=\vec{C}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})-\vec{B}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{C})\qquad (2).
\end{equation}

Based on (1), we can substitute, in (2), $\vec{B}\circ(\vec{C}\times\vec{A})$ for $\vec{C}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})$, then $\vec{A}\circ(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})=\vec{B}\circ(\vec{C}\times\vec{A})-\vec{B}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{C})$. And since $\vec{B}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{C})=-\vec{B}\circ(\vec{C}\times\vec{A})$, then
\begin{equation}
\vec{A}\circ(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})=2\left(\vec{B}\circ(\vec{C}\times\vec{A})\right).
\end{equation}

We also get
\begin{equation}
\vec{A}\circ(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})=2\left(\vec{C}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})\right)
\end{equation}
by substituting, in (2), $-\vec{C}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})$ for $\vec{B}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{C})$.

It's clear that the obtained results doesn't match the equalities in (1), unless (2) becomes
\begin{equation}
\vec{A}\circ(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{C}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})-\vec{B}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{C})\right) \qquad (3).
\end{equation}
So what's wrong ?

**Note that**, in many books of vector calculus one can find the equality
\begin{equation}
\vec{\nabla}\circ(\vec{U}\times\vec{V})=\vec{V}\circ(\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{U})-\vec{U}\circ(\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{V})\qquad (4)
\end{equation}
which means that (2) is true without $\frac{1}{2}$, just by substituting $\vec{\nabla}$ for $\vec{A}$, $\vec{U}$ for $\vec{B}$, and $\vec{V}$ for $\vec{C}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably there is an equals sign missing in your reference and it's meant to read

$$\vec{A}\cdot(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})=\vec{C}\cdot(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})=-\vec{B}\cdot(\vec{A}\times\vec{C})$$

---

**UPDATE** to address questions raised in the comments: for a counterexample, note that

$$(1,0,0) \cdot \bigg[(0,1,0) \times (0,0,1)\bigg] = (1,0,0) \cdot (1,0,0) = 1$$

whereas

\begin{align*}
(0,0,1) &\cdot \bigg[(1,0,0) \times (0,1,0)\bigg]  - (0,1,0) \cdot \bigg[(1,0,0) \times (0,0,1)\bigg] \\
&= (0,0,1) \cdot (0,0,1) - (0,1,0) \cdot (0, -1, 0) \\
&= 1 - (-1) = 2
\end{align*}

---

To address the apparent similarity to the product rule for divergence,
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\vec{U}\times\vec{V})=\vec{V}\cdot(\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{U})-\vec{U}\cdot(\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{V}),$$
let's look at what happens in the one-dimensional case.  Suppose that $a, b, c$ are real numbers.  Then

$$a b c = c a b = b a c$$

so in particular we have

$$a b c = \frac{1}{2} (b a c + c a b).$$

On the other hand, suppose that $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$.  Then by the product rule,

$$\frac{d}{dx} \; u \; v = u \; \frac{d}{dx} \; v + v \; \frac{d}{dx} \; u$$

The preceding two equations look very similar except for the factor of 1/2, but clearly they do not *actually* have much to do with one another.  In particular, the chain rule from Calculus 1 does *not* come from taking the first equation, substituting $a = d/dx$, and somehow dealing with the factor of 2.  The apparent similarity is essentially a coincidence.

---

So we should ask ourselves: what's the difference here, at a fundamental level?  Well, multiplication of real numbers (or functions) is commutative, but "multiplication" by the differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ is not; 
$a b c$ is the same thing as $b a c$, but
$$\frac{d}{dx} \; u \; v$$
is *not* the same thing as 
$$u \; \frac{d}{dx} \; v$$

The three-dimensional case you're looking at here is entirely analogous to the one-dimensional case I've described above, with "commutative" replaced by "anti-commutative."  In fact, if you go ahead and expand your (1) and (3) in coordinates, you'll see it essentially reduces to the one-dimensional case.

---

As to why certain identities among vectors hold when replacing a vector with a $\vec{\nabla}$: not every identity makes use of the commutativity of multiplication in a fundamental way.

Comment: But this equality is already stated in (1) since $\vec{B}\circ(\vec{C}\times\vec{A})=-\vec{B}\circ(\vec{A}\times\vec{C})$

Comment: Yes.  I think your source was just stating a slightly-differently-worded version of (1).

Comment: If you show us the actual source perhaps we can say more.

Comment: Equalities of (1) are surely true and that's easy to verify them. The problem is with equation (2), it is cannot be verified by the equalities of (1).
The reference of (2) is https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Poynting

Comment: Equation (2), as you've written it, is false.

Comment: Relationship (2) is definitely erroneous : take  for $A,B,C$ an orthonormal basis, you will get 1=2...

Comment: I agree that (2) is false, but as I said, it verify (4). And if we substitute, in (3),  $\vec{\nabla}$ for $\vec{A}$, $\vec{U}$ for $\vec{B}$, and $\vec{V}$ for $\vec{C}$, compared to (4), there will be a missing $\frac{1}{2}$ .

Comment: You can't just plug $\nabla$ into an equation that's true for vectors and get a valid statement.  Multiplication of numbers commutes; "multiplication" with a differential operator does not.  The fact that equations (3) and (4) look somewhat similar is purely coincidental.

Comment: It's really strange. In all vector calculus identities we can simply put $\vec{\nabla}$ instead of any vector to have the identities for divergence and curl. Can you give a counter-example ?

Comment: @Sofiane: I've added additional material to the answer to address your questions.